# How to load image formats based on browser support using CSS?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, background-image, webp

I would like to use the [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) image format in my CSS `background-image` property. But, since WebP is quite new and still not supported by all browsers new and old, I would also like to add support for a JPEG version of that image as a fallback.

I know I can use the `<picture>` tag to do this like:

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="image.webp">
    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="image.jpg">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</picture>
```

And this would make the browser load the first supported format. But can I achieve the same effect somehow using only CSS, since I am setting a background image using the `background-image` property? I know I can select images based on screen size using `@media` queries, but how do I load images based on browser support?

I have tried to search for a solution, but could not find one. Let me know if this is a duplicate and the solution already exists.

Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate you writing out how you can do it with `<picture>` as that's exactly what *I* needed.

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS `@supports` instead.

```
.yourclass {
    background: url("image.jpg") no-repeat center / contain;
}

@supports (background-image: url("image.webp")) {
    .yourclass {
        background: url("image.webp") no-repeat center / contain;
    }
}
```

Don't worry. Open the inspector and you'll notice the browser **won't load both images**.

Things to consider:

- Notice you must declare the `webp` version **after** the `jpg`, or the
  cascade flow should win.
- The `background-repeat`, `background-position` and `background-size` params are just for example purpose.

Comment: Looked promising, but testing on Safari I find that despite not being able to use webp, it will use the rules inside the @supports part.

Comment: I've also tested on Safari, this answer is not correct. I think `@supports` only tests this CSS rule is available and valid for the current browser, but won't tell you whether the resource can be loaded successfully.

Comment: @bambooom what version of Safari did you test with? https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries

Comment: @ed1nh0 Safari Version 13.0.5 (15608.5.11). I don't mean `@supports` is not supported on Safari. But I agree with the first comment. This @supports feature queries return true for Safari 13, so that the rule `url("image.webp")` is applied, but the webp cannot be shown on Safari.

Answer (score -2):

Use 2 background-images:
one with JPG or PNG the other one is with WEBP the browser will automatically choose the best one.

Found this code on codepen by:Robin Rendle

CSS:

```
element {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14179/cust-housegreening-pup%402x-4cf7ada520811031a97bee12c06d9e9367f811bd86255ea60d40aa809cf58801.jpg');
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14179/cust-housegreening-pup@2x-4cf7ada520811031a97bee12c06d9e9367f811bd86255ea60d40aa809cf58801.webp');
}
```

https://codepen.io/robinrendle/pen/ORmzJY

Comment: I can confirm that this approach does NOT work. While using this approach, both FireFox and Google Chrome downloads the `.webp` version of the image and works fine. But on Safari (v12.1.1), which does not support WebP, this does not work. Safari still tries to download the `.webp` format and does not show the image. This is the intended behaviour of CSS since when you use multiple `background-image` attributes, the browser always downloads the last mentioned image. Even the codepen you provided does not work on Safari.

Comment: Sorry about that, tested this on current browser the only way is using JS to detect the webp support and add a body class so all elements with background images can be switched to webp

Comment: you can refer to this link:https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/ and this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/make-your-website-load-lightning-fast-with-webp-images-cf55c98ac0a2/